# Eclipse Project Collaboration Remotely

Tags: eclipse

Just a quick question; Best way to collaboratively work on a project with someone else remotely in eclipse? Realistically it'll probably just be 2-4 people using it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an eclipse specific question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a good version control system.  Git, utilizing pull requests, works quite well.  Any answer beyond that is well outside of the scope of a stack overflow issue.  If you can come up with the "best way" to accomplish this, you'll be a billionaire.